# How to monitor linux spinlock waiting time?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, spinlock

I read the spinlock function code in the linux kernel. There are two functions related to spinlock. See the code below:

```
static __always_inline void __ticket_spin_lock(raw_spinlock_t *lock)
{
    short inc = 0x0100;

    asm volatile (
        LOCK_PREFIX "xaddw %w0, %1\n"
        "1:\t"
        "cmpb %h0, %b0\n\t"
        "je 2f\n\t"
        "rep ; nop\n\t"
        "movb %1, %b0\n\t"
        /* don't need lfence here, because loads are in-order */
        "jmp 1b\n"
        "2:"
        : "+Q" (inc), "+m" (lock->slock)
        :
        : "memory", "cc");
}
static __always_inline void __ticket_spin_lock(raw_spinlock_t *lock)
{
    int inc = 0x00010000;
    int tmp;

    asm volatile(LOCK_PREFIX "xaddl %0, %1\n"
             "movzwl %w0, %2\n\t"
             "shrl $16, %0\n\t"
             "1:\t"
             "cmpl %0, %2\n\t"
             "je 2f\n\t"
             "rep ; nop\n\t"
             "movzwl %1, %2\n\t"
             /* don't need lfence here, because loads are in-order */
             "jmp 1b\n"
             "2:"
             : "+r" (inc), "+m" (lock->slock), "=&r" (tmp)
             :
             : "memory", "cc");
}
```

I have two question:

1.What's the difference between the two functions above?

2.What can I do to monitor the spinlock waiting time(the time it takes to first try the lock and finally get the lock)?does the variable inc means the spinlock waiting time?

Comment: 1) Not much. Looks like they're just using different values to indicate the "locked" state. 2) You could add a counter to the code. As it stands, there isn't anything that counts the number of repetitions. However, you could also surround your locking code with `rdtsc` cycle counts for a rough measure.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. Does the line "rep ; nop\n\t" means spin busy waiting?

Comment: No - that's just a "yield". Modern processors have a dedicated `pause` instruction. The spinning is the `jmp 1`. (Maybe check out [this article](http://wiki.osdev.org/Spinlock).)

Comment: @KerrekSB, Could you help me add a unsigned long counter(monitor the spinning time ) in the asm code, I'm not familiar with the asm code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first explain how the spinlock code works. We have variables

```c
uint16_t inc = 0x0100,
         lock->slock;     // I'll just call this "slock"
```

In the assembler code, `inc` is referred to as `%0` and `slock` as `%1`. Moreover, `%b0` denotes the lower 8 bit, i.e. `inc % 0x100`, and `%h0` is `inc / 0x100`.

Now:

```
lock xaddw %w0, %1    ;; "inc := slock"  and  "slock := inc + slock"
                      ;; simultaneously (atomic exchange and increment)
1:
    cmpb %h0, %b0     ;; "if (inc / 256 == inc % 256)"
    je 2f             ;; "    goto 2;"
    rep ; nop         ;; "yield();"
    movb %1, %b0      ;; "inc = slock;"
    jmp 1b            ;; "goto 1;"
2:
```

Comparing the upper and lower byte of `inc` succeeds if `inc` is zero. Since `inc` has the value of the original lock, this happens if the lock is unlocked. In that case, the lock will already have been in­cre­ment­ed to non-zero by the atomic exchange-and-increment, so it is now locked.

Otherwise, i.e. if the lock had already been locked, we pause a little, then update `inc` to the current value of the lock, and try again.

(I believe there's actually a possiblity for an overflow, if 2<sup>8</sup> threads simultaneously attempt to get the spinlock. In that case, `slock` is updated to 0x0100, 0x0200, ... 0xFF00, 0x0000, and would then appear to be unlocked. Maybe that's why the second version of the code uses a 16-bit wide counter, which would require 2<sup>16</sup> simultaneous attempts.)

Now let's insert a counter:

```c
uint32_t spincounter = 0;

asm volatile( /* code below */
    : "+Q" (inc), "+m" (lock->slock)
    : "=r" (spincounter)
    : "memory", "cc");
```

Now `spincounter` may be referred to as `%2`. We just need to increment the counter each time:

```
1:
    inc %2
    cmpb %h0, %b0
    ;; etc etc
```

I haven't tested this, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Yes, the first code only works with <= 255 CPUS.  That's why there is the different versions of the low-level spinlock asm code using 16-bit counters, and there is a CPP test "#if (CONFIG_NR_CPUS < 256)" in the source to decide which to use at compile time.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks! That's great to know. (I forgot that "threads" isn't as useful a concept in kernel space as "CPUs" is.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB.Thank you very much. I tried your code in the linux kernel, but it didn't give any output information about the spinlock waiting time information. Could you tell me where am wrong? My computer's architecture is x86_64 and my os linux-2.6.31.10.

Comment: @Charles0429: Did you log the value of the `spincounter` variable? What does it say?

Comment: @KerrekSB. Yes, I tried to log the spincounter variable from the virtual machine to the xen hypervisor, but it didn't generate any output. And I tried to write a illegal statement in the file which contains ticket_spinlock, to my surprise, no errors encounter, So I wonder ticket spinlock is used in linux-kernel 2.6.31.10? although what i googled is "ticket spinlock is used by x86 architecture since linux kenerl 2.6.25".

Comment: @KerrekSB： I also tried to use printk function to log the variable spincounter, it didn't output either. Could you give me some advice on what can i do next?

Comment: @Charles0429: Hm, sorry, I'm not very familiar with kernel development. You can always test the spinlock code separately in userspace, though!

Comment: @KerrekSB: What's the difference between spinlock in userspace and spinlock in kernel space?